# How to use if statement inside elif in shell script?

Tags: shell

How to use if statement inside elif in shell script?

```
if condition #if condn
then
   statments
elif
   statements
   if cond1
   then
   statement
   if
else
statemnet
```

Comment: Did you try googling?

Comment: What? Where is the condition after `elif`? currently that would act as an `else`...

Answer (score 1):

`elif` requires a command, and `fi` terminates an if command

```
if command1
then
   statments
elif command2
then
   statements
   if command3
   then
       statements
   fi
else
    statements
fi
```